# Operating system not found while booting pendrive ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, usb-drive, 22.04

I am using linux mint 20.3. I want to use ubuntu 22.04 . but when i boot my pendrive , it shows me that operating system not found . it is happening with me with every ubuntu distro after 20.04 like 20.10, 21.10 and 22.04. ubuntu 20.04 works fine.
my laptop is Dell XPS 15-L502x with intel 2520m .
made from balena etcher
plz help me from this problem

[image]

Comment: Are you using an appropriate method to write your ISO to thumb-drive, as changes were made in the ISO & booting in the releases you mention (*20.10 & later*) so all architectures Ubuntu is made for boot the same way, meaning some software had to be updated to write the ISO correctly. Are you writing your ISO with updated & valid software for the release you're trying to use?

Comment: yeah i am writing through balena etcher and i havent faced any issue with this software

Comment: Can that version of software cope with the later releases of Ubuntu; as it sounds like it cannot.  If it is using a direct *clone* it should work; however it you use a non-clone ISO write mode you'll discover you cannot successfully boot releases later than 20.10, which is what you're describing (*why the software has to be upgraded to cope with the changes that started in the groovy or 20.10 cycle as all architectures of Ubuntu ISOs now boot the same*)

Comment: so can you tell me what to do

Comment: The tutorials on writing an ISO to thumb-drive can be found here for Ubuntu / MacOS / windows  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview   Balena Etcher should work (MacOS) if the version is *up-to-date*  ...   I can't confirm that is your issue; just your mention of releases that work/don't work fit non-updated ISO writing software.

Comment: Yes, Balena Etcher should work (and it does direct clone as always). Your screenshot shows it's trying to boot from the network (PXE). Are you sure you're selecting the USB to boot from?

Comment: @guiverc: Etcher has a version for Linux x64, (AppImage): https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases/download/v1.7.9/balena-etcher-electron-1.7.9-linux-x64.zip?d_id=e7f87540-a6ee-4b35-828e-da044bda2299R and for Linux x86. However Gnome Disks will do the same thing and comes with Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, now i use Rufus instead of Balena and it works for Live USB.

For this notebook model, i cannot run Ubuntu 22, neither with manual partition nor with LVM and encryption. ["Operation System not found" after installation]

I thought it was an EFI Problem...but Partitions already created.

Do you have Ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).